# What is meaning of underscore(_) in python function import?

Tags: python

I've inherited some code with imports in each function and using underscores for each module imported as below

```py
def my_func():
    from foo import bar as _bar
    from spam import meat as _meat

    # Do some work
```

What is the point in the `_bar`? All imports are done like this.

Comment: Maybe to distinguish them from other variables? Also useful if you’re paid by the keystroke.

Comment: If you see this done at module scope, it suppresses those names from being exported as public. But here, within a function def, there is no point - since these name bindings are to local variables anyway. Probably the person who wrote the code is just not very experienced in Python.

Comment: In addition to @Ry- it's possible there are other methods/variables with the same name, this could be a way of avoiding collisions, but if not, it's a bit off.

Comment: @wim So this could be worthwhile at the top of a file but not within a function?

Comment: @jeff_27  Yes.  But the more usual (and better) pattern is to define a module's public names explicitly using `__all__`.

Answer (score 1):

If the actual names are things that exist as a part of the built in commands in python, this is done as a way to avoid shadowing those built in functions (for example - `from mymodule import open` would make the built in `open` which returns file handles inaccessble).  Otherwise, it's simply convention for the original author.

Answer (score -1):

I believe functions with name starting with a single underscore can't be imported using this line :

```py
from module import *
```

for example this module :

```py
def _some_function_1():
    pass
def some_function_2():
    pass
```

if you imported this module, you will be able to access only `some_function_2()`

Comment: Those *"functions"* don't have their name starting with a single underscore. It's alias.

Comment: Can’t import out of a function’s scope, though.